# Finding the correct FFC Cable (flexible flat cable)

Tags: pcb, connector, ffc

I have this device which has 2 PCBs, they are connected to each other using this slot, i've counted the pins and the number is 70, i want to have the board connected to each other using a cable instead of being stick together over this socket, reason is i want to probe the board and having them stuck together makes it difficult, extending their distance will help alot, your answers are appreciated

[image: top and down pcb socket]

Comment: Do you have the manufacturers part number for the socket shown in the picture? With a part number, hopefully will be able to find the datasheet for the socket which will contain dimensions to help finding a suitable FFC cable.

Answer (score 0):

That is a board-to-board connector. That means its family includes only PCB headers. It does not include any cable-mounted plugs. Therefore, the only way to make a cable that separates the boards is to make a custom FPC (Flexible Printed Circuit) and solder a pair of those connectors onto it. As I am sure you understand, that is not cheap and not straightforward.

Identifying that connector would require two additional pieces of information:

1. The **exact** [pitch](https://forum.digikey.com/t/pitch-of-a-connector/172)
2. Pictures of its mate

Even if you do go through all that trouble, I must caution that, if this connector carries high-speed signals, the product may no longer work through an extension cable due to the additional delays, mismatched impedance, waveform deformation from additional reactance, cross talk, and receiving electrical noise from nearby sources.

Comment: Thank you Davide